# How can I flaten a list of items that each may have a list?

Tags: kotlin, collections, flatten

If I have something like this:

```
data class BaseItem {
  val id: Int
  val itemName: String
  val type: String
  val relatedItems: List<BaseItem>?
}
```

If I have a `List<BaseItem>` how could I use flat/map etc to create a new `List<BaseItem>` that would contain an entry for each `BaseItem` followed by all the items in the `subgroup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
list.flatMap { item ->
    mutableListOf(item).apply {
        item.relatedItems?.let(::addAll)
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I change a member variable of `item` on the fly in this approach? E.g. when doing `mutableListOf(item)` I would like to have a flag true while `let(::addAll)` should have that flag as false

Comment: Since you are using a data class you could do `mutableListOf(item.copy(flag = true))`

Comment: So this works! But if I understand this, it creates a new `ArrayList` for each `item`. Is there a more efficient way?